# Trying to convert a .dat file to usable text

Tags: file, gps

I'm looking for where to begin with this conversion. I have very limited coding experience (FLL parent) and virtually no support from the software company generating the files.

I am trying to take a data file generated by aircraft avionics that stores GPS waypoint information and read / write new information into it from a PC. The company I work for uses hundreds of waypoints and right now the only way we can create new ones is to do so through the avionics software, which is incredibly time-consuming. I can upload and download the file from the avionics onto a thumb drive but I have no idea how to read it. I opened it in a hex editor and can read the waypoint names, but the GPS coordinates are just garbled text characters.

Where do I start looking for answers? is this something I could convert in C++ or something similar without an overwhelming learning curve?

Thanks in advance.